# typing: How to bind owner class to generic descriptor?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-descriptors

Can I implement a generic descriptor in Python in a way it will support/respect/understand inheritance hierarchy of his owners?

It should be more clear in the code:

```
from typing import (
    Generic, Optional, TYPE_CHECKING,
    Type, TypeVar, Union, overload,
)

T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")  # noqa

class Descr(Generic[T]):

    @overload
    def __get__(self: "Descr[T]", instance: None, owner: Type[T]) -> "Descr[T]": ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self: "Descr[T]", instance: T, owner: Type[T]) -> T: ...

    def __get__(self: "Descr[T]", instance: Optional[T], owner: Type[T]) -> Union["Descr[T]", T]:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance


class A:
    attr: int = 123
    descr = Descr[T]()  # I want to bind T here, but don't know how


class B(A):
    new_attr: int = 123
    qwerty: str = "qwe"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        reveal_type(a.descr)  # mypy guess it is T? but I want A*
    print("a.attr =", a.descr.attr)  # mypy error: T? has no attribute "attr"
                                     # no runtime error
    b = B()
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        reveal_type(b.descr)  # mypy said it's T? but I want B*

    print("b.new_attr =", b.descr.new_attr)  # mypy error: T? has no attribute "new_attr"
                                             # no runtime error
    print("b.qwerty =", b.descr.qwerty)  # mypy error: T? has no attribute "qwerty"
                                         # (no runtime error)
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/nobbynobbs/4a18b4f4466a7eee58d44b5bfcf10532) - almost the same code snippet on gist

Comment: Just to be sure: You want ``X.descr`` to be of type ``Descr[X]`` for any ``X <: A`` (subclass)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I want to bind actual type of subclass to descriptor for all subclasses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if you *need* to have the descriptor class as generic; it will probably just suffice to have `__get__` on an instance of `Type[T]` to return `T`:

```
T = TypeVar("T")  # noqa

class Descr:
    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: Type[T]) -> "Descr": ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: T, owner: Type[T]) -> T: ...

    def __get__(self, instance: Optional[T], owner: Type[T]) -> Union["Descr", T]:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance


class A:
    attr: int = 123
    descr = Descr()


class B(A):
    new_attr: int = 123
    qwerty: str = "qwe"
```

And every example of yours works as you wanted, and you *will* get an error for

```
print("b.spam =", b.descr.spam)
```

which produces

```
error: "B" has no attribute "spam"
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I just removed Generic from my snippet and everything works like I want now. Pycharm still doesn't understand it, but mypy does.

Comment: Yeah IIRC PyCharm was rather dummy with descriptors anyway... Edit - seems to support basic types but it cannot infer based on how it is called...